# ASP.NET MVC 4 RC Missing Use HTML5 Semantic Markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 - SP1

I installed ASP.NET MVC 4.0 RC on my box. The option "Use HTML5 semantic markup" is missing in all the project templates (empty application, Web Api, Internet app, Intranet App) when creating a new project of ASP.NET MVC 4.0 Web Application project type.

Remember, I have not installed asp.net mvc 4 beta prior to RC installation. However, this option is present when creating an asp.net mvc 3.0 web application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to install this extension :

[Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83)

Also consider installing [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f). It add a tons of useful tools related to web development.

Comment: -1 the extension and the option are two different things. The extension adds features to Visual Studio. The option modifies Razor's HTML output, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721056/new-use-html5-semantic-markup-option-on-file-new-mvc-3-project